# Modal pop up after submitting form on the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, servlets

I am a total novice and i don't know how to make this.

*What I want:*

When I click submit on my page's form, it will go to the servlet and load the data in the database. Then as a confirmation of load, it show a success modal.
I want to achieve something in which the servlet does not redirect. That is, it stays on the same page and show a "Data lodaded successfully" modal that pops up.

I am using `response.sendRedirect` to redirect to another page in my servlet
but I don't want to redirect, I want to stay in the same page with a pop up appearing in the form page.

Comment: why dont you redirect to SELF, and return a bit value saying that it needs to load a pop up a alert box at the ui side. on load of the page check for this bit and call the pop up window in jquery. **REF:http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/**

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that very easily by using jquery-ui.

You can add jquery-ui in 2 ways:

1) Put this links inside your `<head>` tags

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

OR

2) Download the files and add them to your website (same as above but files will be on your domain). **Recommended**

You create an empty div anywhere inside you `<body>` tags:

```
<div id="modal_popup">
</div>
```

You then add the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(function() {
    $( "#modal_popup" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 140,
      modal: true,
      title: "The title of your modal popup",
      open: function(){
        $( "#modal_popup" ).append("The text that you want in the modal.");
      }
    });
  });
  $( "#submit_id" ).click(function(){ $( "#modal_popup" ).dialog('open'); });
});
</script>
```

**EDIT**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function pop_up_modal() {
    $( "#modal_popup" ).dialog({
      height: 140,
      modal: true,
      title: "The title of your modal popup",
      open: function(){
        $( "#modal_popup" ).append("The text that you want in the modal.");
      }
    });
  };
</script>
```

You can then call `pop_up_modal()` anywhere on your servlet.

Comment: I appreciate your support.. :) however if i understood what you have said... u mean on submit button it will load the modal. and the servlet will do its job on the background..

But i was referring that if data is not properly loaded in the database by the servlet(say some error occoured), then it will still show the modal because it is associated with the html page but not with the response of the servlet.

if there is any way to fix this.. you are truely welcome.. :)

Comment: i.e: what i mean to say is... 
if data load is successful

if (rs>1) then success modal on the same html form page and after X time redirect to home
if false the error modal on the same html form page and redirect to form page again.. :)

simple as that.. :)

Comment: You don't have to run the script on the submit button. You can put it on the page that loads the data to the db as well and execute it as soon as the data has been submitted. You can then have a success or fail message modal and redirect from there using `response.sendRedirect`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) Modal

Basically you can use a button with `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"` or call directly via JS:

```
$('#myModal').modal('show');
```

[Test it here.](http://jsfiddle.net/zSCaC/)